# Convert .txt file to SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, swift3, static-libraries

Large hierarchical static data to be bundled into the app. Files are in .txt format.

After thorough research, I found termsql as one of the option to convert text file to SQLite: https://tobimensch.github.io/termsql/

Not able to find tutorials on how to do the conversion. Am I on the right path? Is there any other way that I can code?

My present plan of action: 
Convert .txt file to SQLite. 
Populate the table views from the sql database (4 level hierarchical data)
Bundle the .sql file along with the app itself

Comment: We don't know what the content and structure of your text files. Also, we don't know your expected output. So we are unable to help.

Comment: For further informtion read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are always other ways you can write code. Write some code to open and parse the text file, and make SQLite calls to create the records. Try to be more specific in your question, because what you're asking is too broad to have a specific answer.

Comment: termsql is a decent tool.

Answer (score 0):

If it's all static data then why parse and process inside your app at all? Just prepare all that stuff before adding it into your app.

Now your app only needs to open up the already fully populated sqlite database and it's good to go.

Comment: How do i convert .text into SQLite DB? Sorry I am new to SQLite. And text files are large too for manual conversion.

Comment: Just write some code. Open the txt file and convert each line to SQL according to your table structure, output to another file.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what language do you know?

Comment: I know swift and partly xml. From non-engineering background. Trying to solve a problem in my domain - healthcare.